# Could you explain if then elif and else syntax of jq?

Tags: jq

I am a novice on jq. 
While studying if then else end syntax of jq manual,  I got strange result as follows:

```java
$ echo '[0, 1, 2]' | jq 'if .[] == 0 then "zero" elif .[] == 1 then "one" else "many" end'
"zero"
"many"
"one"
"many"
"many"
"one"
"many"
```

Does anybody explain the above result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [if/then/else/end](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else) syntax itself is straightforward, but when you embed iterators within the subexpressions, you get the "combinatorial" behavior you noticed.

In other words, each occurrence of `.[]` is expanded independently of the others when it is encountered.

Perhaps it will be easier to understand if you start with a single iterator, e.g.

```bash
echo '[0, 1, 2]' | 
  jq '.[] | if . == 0 then "zero" elif . == 1 then "one" else "many" end'
```